# Which Android file manager supports sorting directories by their actual size?

Tags: android, file-management

Which Android file manager supports sorting directories by their "actual size"? By "actual size" I mean size in bytes calculated recursively as a sum of all sub directories and their content. Please recommend a paid or free file manager, or similar tool, which can do that. There are many file managers for Android listed in Google Play but it's difficult to figure out support for specific features.

Motivation: even after cleaning all picture and documents, and most applications, on my tablet using standard Android tools, the internal storage is still reported as full. I need to get hands dirty and investigate what holds that space.

I originally asked this on [Android Enthusiats](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/244974/which-file-manager-supports-sorting-directories-by-their-actual-size).

Comment: What if it's not a file manager, but still matches your motivation? If I understand correctly, you're looking for an app to perform [Storage Analysis](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_storageanalysis) (disclosure: link goes to my website), right? Several apps available for that. If one of those matches your needs, be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Ghost Commander File Manager in Play Store. It will sort by directory with subdirectories included.

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot showing this sorting? Thanks and welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

[DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en&gl=US) is going to do your work perfectly.
It shows actual size by adding sub-directories and shows a graph type representation. And it automatically sorts by descending file size. (You can confirm by screenshots).
And the app is completely free, open source and does not use trackers.

Check its screenshots:

[image: DiskUsage]

Comment: Seems that it's not available on Play Store anymore